# How to search the whole of bash history without needing to go forwards and backwards?

Tags: bash, command-history

At times when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to search through command history, I find that I don't reach the entry I was looking for, even though I know it's in history. I think this is due to me having passed the entry, forcing me to use another command to go the other direction. Is there a command that allows the whole of history to be searched by looping through it (restarting the cycle) when it reaches the end?

Comment: So it should loop from first to last rather than stopping at the first?

Comment: @mikel Yeah, that's right.

Comment: Perhaps you need a better way to search.  Maybe just running `history | grep <something>` then running `!<number>` would be a way of doing it?

Comment: @mik That's quite a bit to type :(

Comment: So make an alias or function for it. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> to go back to the end of your history then search again, but maybe you knew that, and it's not what you want.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to make it wrap around.

I can't see anything about it in `man bash` or `man readline`.

We could try writing a `readline` macro, but there's no variable telling us what line of history we're on.

So short of that, here's some other suggestions that you might find viable alternatives:

---

If your terminal is configured to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, (e.g. by running `stty stop undef`), then you can change directions just by pressing it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

---

You could use `history | grep <whatever>` then type `!<number from left column>` to run it.

If that's too long to type, make it a function to save some typing, e.g.

```
hgrep() {
    history | grep "$@"
}
```

---

Set up `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward`.  They can be easier to use.

e.g. `ls` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>  will search backwards thru all your `ls` commands.

Plus you can change directions just by pressing the other shortcut, e.g. if you're at the oldest command, you can just switch from pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Set it up by putting this in your `/etc/inputrc` or `.inputrc` for `bash`:

```
$if mode=emacs
"\ep": history-search-backward
"\en": history-search-forward
$endif
```

and this in your `.zshrc` for `zsh`:

```
bindkey -M emacs '^[p' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey -M emacs '^[n' history-beginning-search-forward
```

You could even go one step further and make the Up arrow do this.

---

Finally, are you sure the command is being entered into history?  Maybe it's being ignored due to the `HISTCONTROL` or `HISTIGNORE` settings, or it's falling off the end due to `HISTSIZE`?

Comment: Be careful with `Ctrl-S`: [it can freeze your terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12107/4319) unless you have done some re-configuration beforehand.