# How to get history search to start afresh?

Tags: bash, command-history

When I do a search using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, the search gets limited to entries older than displayed hit. How do I reset this so that it starts from the beginning (i.e. from latest history entry) without leaving the shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search the whole of bash history without needing to go forwards and backwards?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7061/how-to-search-the-whole-of-bash-history-without-needing-to-go-forwards-and-backwa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will abort the search; starting a new one will begin with the latest history entry again

Comment: +1 Disappointingly, neither shortcut resumes the search after pressing `Ctrl+R` again, and `Ctrl+G` is easier to type than `Alt+>`.

Comment: @Mikel Oh, I misunderstood the question. You're right; I'm not sure how to do that